# picamera モジュールが利用できない

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

初期状態のラズベリーパイにPython 2.7.10をインストールしました。

```
$ ./configure && make && sudo make install
$ sudo apt-get install python-picamera
```

ここまでは順調なような気がしていましたが、Pythonからpicameraを見つけることが
できていないのか・・・といった感じです。

```
>>> picamera
　Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
　NameError: name 'picamera' is not defined
```

となってしまいます。

=sample.py=

```
  File "sample.py", line 3, in <module>
    import picamera
 ImportError: No module named picamera
```

`python -c "help('modules')"` を実施すると、一覧にはpicameraは存在していません。

`sudo apt-get install python-picamera`をそのまま実施しても「最新です」とメッセージが表示されます。インストールログらしきものも確認したのですが、特にエラーもなさそうな。（見るところが違うかもしれませんが・・・）

この場合、どこかのパスを書き換えるか、picameraのインストール先を変更するようになるのでしょうか？自分なりに調べたのですが、Linuxをほとんど触ったことがないのもあり、全く持って行き詰まっております。どなたかご教示いただければ幸いです。

上記pythonインストール方法だとインストール先は/usr/local/lib/ のpython2.7フォルダで認識はあっているでしょうか？
各種モジュールは上記インストール方法だとどこへインストールされるのでしょうか？
それらを参照するファイルがどこかにあるのだと・・・。
picameraのモジュールインストール先を、単純に変更した方が素人には簡単でしょうか？

(↓この２つまでは成功しています。)

```
　raspistill -o aaa.jpg
  gpicview aaa.jpg
```

##### コメントに対する回答、確認したこと

・ dpk-Lについて $ dpkg -L python-picamera
　　　　　　　　　　/usr/share/pyshared/picamera/camera.py

・usr/lib/にもpython2.7フォルダがあります。
　usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/picamera/camera.py(ショートカットみたいなマークあり)

・make install
　python2.7.10をダウンロードしてインストールしてます。
wget python.org/ftp/python/2.7.10/Python-2.7.10.tgz

・>>> import sys
　>>> sys.path
['', '/usr/local/lib/python27.zip', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python2.s7/site-packages']

・python -c "help('modules')"
　picameraは表示されませんでした。

・=sample.py=
import sys
sys.path.append('/usr/share/pyshared/picamera/')←試しに追記しましたが駄目でした
import picamera

あまりの前進なさにへこんでいます。

Comment: `import picamera`が失敗するのは変ですね。`dpkg -L python-picamera`するとどうなりますか？パッケージでインストールする場合、`/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages`の下に入るのが普通です。そこに入っていますか？

Comment: `which python`を実行した結果を載せてください。最初のmake installは一体何をインストールしているのですか？ひょっとしてPythonをインストールしているでしょうか？もしそうならシステムの標準のPythonを使わないとダメです

Comment: 質問者です。ご質問ありがとうございます。

ご質問いただいた内容は投稿の最後に記述させていただきました。
ラズベリーパイはpython2.7.10が最新だと思ってインストールしております。そもそも、そこがいけなかったのでしょうか？

Comment: Pythonはシステムに最初から入っているものを使いましょう。新たにインストール必要は通常ないはずです。apt-getでパッケージを入れるならシステムのPythonを使うことが前提です。

Answer (score 1):

`/usr/bin/python`というようにフルパスで起動すれば`import picamera`が動くでしょう。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございました。
私のような自己解決できない人がそのような事をしてはいけませんね。
初期化を実施し、最初からやり直します。ありがとうございました。